# how do i take values from an object inside an array and put them inside a array in column?

Tags: javascript

I have a query that returns two columns with values, `name` and `win` like this:

```
[
  RowDataPacket { name: 'mattia', win: 45 },
  RowDataPacket { name: 'mauro', win: 32 },
  RowDataPacket { name: 'valerio', win: 30 },
  RowDataPacket { name: 'luca', win: 29 },
  RowDataPacket { name: 'lorenzo', win: 26 },
  RowDataPacket { name: 'stefano', win: 25 },
  RowDataPacket { name: 'armando', win: 16 },
  RowDataPacket { name: 'marco', win: 12 },
  RowDataPacket { name: 'francesco', win: 10 },
  RowDataPacket { name: 'antonio', win: 5 }
]
```

and I want to take each value and put it in an array in the order where values are and put them in column.
i tried to use `.map` but couldn't get it to work properly

Comment: What is the expected result of function you are trying to implement?

Comment: I'm trying to have those values in column like this: 
`[ 
mattia,
mauro,
valerio,
luica,
etc..
 ]` same thing for the wins

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what are you looking for?

```js
const results = [
  { name: 'mattia', win: 45 },
  { name: 'mauro', win: 32 },
  { name: 'valerio', win: 30 },
  { name: 'luca', win: 29 },
  { name: 'lorenzo', win: 26 },
  { name: 'stefano', win: 25 },
  { name: 'armando', win: 16 },
  { name: 'marco', win: 12 },
  { name: 'francesco', win: 10 },
  { name: 'antonio', win: 5 }
];

// solution #1 - every map iterates over the whole array (2x iterations)
const names = results.map(result => result.name);
const wins = results.map(result => result.win);

console.log('names', names);
console.log('wins', wins);

// solution #2 - iterates once over the array
const { namesArr, winsArr } = results.reduce((accumulator, currentValue) => {
  const { name, win } = currentValue;
  const { namesArr, winsArr } = accumulator;
  return { namesArr: [...namesArr, name], winsArr: [...winsArr, win] };
}, { namesArr: [], winsArr: [] })

console.log('names2', namesArr);
console.log('wins2', winsArr);
```